# windows communication foundation (WCF) replacement

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asmx

i was employed by a company 5 years ago. the company still uses .NET 4.5 with WCF.
.NET 4.5 is obsolete while .NET core exist. i tried many times suggesting an upgrade to .NET core, but our CTO refuse under the excuse that we need the WCF due to our servers configuration.
now our servers configuration: we have a load balancer to multiple servers hosting our web applications and the corresponding webservice(asmx), and these servers are then connected to another load balancer for multiple servers hosting the WCF and the database.

I feel we are still stuck in 2005 with our projects getting bigger by the day.

Now, I want to build a strong case why we should upgrade our technologies and present it to the CEO.

if someone can point me into the correct direction with what should be the replacement for WCF in 2021 that will work with how the servers are configured.

thank you for your time

Comment: It's not clear why you would need to upgrade to dotnet core. However, you should upgrade to a supported version of the framework (.NET 4.8)

Comment: Doesn't really change your question but I think .Net Core is already obsolete. You might want to switch to .Net 5.0. Not sure if .Net 5.0 supports WCF. Probably not.

Comment: I'd say it's time to move to the cloud ... but this actually seems more like a Workplace SE ord IPS SE issue. But meanwhile: I found this: https://visualrecode.com/blog/wcf-alternatives-for-net5/

Comment: @AluanHaddad at the moment, i have a huge client interested in one of our projects. but his main condition is to upgrade to at least dotnet core. And if we are able to sign this client, this will be a huge change for the future of the company.

Comment: @bjzero What is your position in the company?

Comment: @bjzero Then that should be the argument that you present to the CEO: client interest.

Comment: @Fildor thank you. I have a huge client right now, and he is requesting a change to at least .net core to sign a contract. and the CTO is refusing to forward the client claim which it's not his decision. so im looking for a technology replacement and not how to solve my issue with the CTO.

Comment: @bjzero All I am saying is: you are on thin ice if you are not at least at a comparable level as CTO. Like head of Sales or something.

Comment: But alas: All of this is off topic for SO.

Comment: Let CTO see the bottleneck of WCF, for example, some Technologies of Microsoft no longer support WCF and have no development prospect, and let him feel that there will be no more iteration and update of this technology, he will naturally look for a new technology to replace it.

Answer (score 2):

There is an opensource project looking to port WCF to .NET Core(and .NET 5+) -> https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF.

This is should be backwardly compatible, but it is still alpha/beta atm.  But its a start.

As an alternative to WCF entirely gRPC is a good place to start -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: To add to this, there is also https://github.com/dotnet/wcf which is a officially Microsoft supported WCF Client library for .Net Core. Though it's just the client.

Comment: @sbecker What I read out of the question is that the whole ecosystem at the OP's has _a lot_ of tech debt and the focus has been on features. I _guess_ if you pull on one string, ... you know where I am going.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no detailed description of the services running on your servers, what should be a replacement is dependent on the kind of services deployed on the servers. (Basic http request, Message queues, duplex bindings for 2 way communications etc.).
WFC supports different communication format in terms of binding configurations ([See different binding format here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/system-provided-bindings)).

Use of Open API/Restful APIs should handle a larger portions of your existing WCF endpoints.
However, gRPC is the new guy in town that supports Point-to-point real-time streaming services. Depending on the types of services hosted on your servers, WebSocket which features bi-directional, full-duplex communication over a persistent TCP connection could be combine with Web API if gRPC is new to your team. [See more reference here.](https://cloud-trends.medium.com/grpc-vs-restful-api-vs-graphql-web-socket-tcp-sockets-and-udp-beyond-client-server-43338eb02e37)